# Finding if a user has already flagged an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, enumeration

I've currently setup an instance where a `Review` has many `Flag`s (via polymorphism)  and a `User` has many flags. Everything works so far but I'd now like to make so that in the view if a user has flagged a particular review a message shows up, *Flag Submitted* instead of a link to flag it.

Right now I'm doing this by first gathering all of the flags that belong to the review then using `any?` to determine if any of them have the current user's id.  I was wondering if there was a faster/more efficient way in doing this? It's the lookup chain that makes me comprehensive to leave it as is.

**Note:** `flaggable` is a local variable which in this case represents a `@review`:

```
<%= render "flag", flaggable: @review %>
```

---

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
end
```

---

```
<div>
  <% if user_signed_in? && flaggable.flags.any? { |r| r.user_id == current_user.id } %>
    <p>Flag Submitted</p>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Flag", [:new, flaggable, :flag], remote: true %>
  <% end %>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && flaggable.flags.exists?(owner: current_user) %>
```

- `any?` is an Array method that loops to check if any condition will return true for each element in the Array which is currently held in-memory.

Take note that `flaggable.flags` is an ActiveRecord::Relation object which extends the Array class, therefore you can use any Array methods for this. However, once you invoke any Array method, all `flaggable.flags` will be stored in-memory, which is by then, and only at that time will the loop to check matching conditions will take place.

- `exists?` is an ActiveRecord method similar to `where` and `find` methods, in which this checks if any condition will return true for each row in the Table in the Database which is not in-memory, and is more optimised for searching, and therefore more efficient.

**UPDATE: (To Explain Further)**

Let's say you have this code

```
1 @users = User.where(is_admin: true)
2 @users = @users.where(age: 20)
3 <% @users.each do |user| %>
4   <%= user.name %>
5 <% end %>
6 <%= 'THERE IS A SANTA USER' if @users.any?{|user| user.name == 'Santa'} %>
```

- At line 1, `@users` is an ActiveRecord::Relation, in which it does not yet access the DB. It only still currently is storing the DB Query in memory.
- At line 2, `@users` has been added a condition that `age should be 20`, so the query now becomes something like `@users = users-who-are-admin-and-age-is-20`. This still is a Query stored in memory. Still no DB access happening yet.
- At line 3, `.each` is called from `@users`. By calling this array method, `@users` which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` now connects and queries the DB, which then returns an Array of users now available for looping as you would expect in a `.each` method. (You will notice that lines starting from 3 are code in the view file)
- At line 6, `.any?` is called from `@users`. Since, `@users` which is still an `ActiveRecord::Relation` but has already accessed database and the Array is already in memory (because of line 3), then `.any?` will no longer access the DB, and will just behave like a normal `.any?` method of an Array class. You will then realize that if there are millions of User records in the DB, then `@users` will occupy a huge amount of memory which is not very good. It will be better to use `.find_each` which stores in-memory partial-by-partial with the downside of more DB calls.

On a side note, be careful of using `.joins` as opposed to `.includes`. `.joins` returns an Array object, while `.includes` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation. Both have their own use-cases.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes this faster/better than using `any?`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. There's this one part of your answer I don't understand. What do you mean when you say: *However, once you invoke any Array method, all flaggable.flags will be stored in-memory, which is by then, and only at that time will the loop to check matching conditions will take place.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in explaining this. You've really helped me understand the difference between the two. +1.